# Git prompt in bash

Tags: linux, git, bash

Does somebody know how to get a prompt like in the following screenshot (from Apricity OS)?

[image]

If possible I'd like to get such an prompt in bash, but if the shell in the image is a different one, maybe I'd like to change if somebody can identify it.

Comment: The search words you're looking for is "Airline". IIRC it was a vim plugin that was ported to a bunch of things.

Comment: Aside: I'm *really* not sure that this is an appropriate fit for StackOverflow. Inasmuch as you're looking for the specific code that generates the prompt shown in your screenshot, it's a request for an off-site resource, and that's explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: [powerline-shell](https://github.com/milkbikis/powerline-shell)

Answer (score 1):

This is provided by [an Apricity-themed variant of](https://github.com/agajews/ApricityOS/tree/6e82bcff4e1ef2a14040b80887f0650c904b32b8/apricityassets/src/apricityassets/.liquidprompt) [liquidprompt](https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt), an adaptive prompt framework for bash and zsh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[poweline-shell](https://github.com/milkbikis/powerline-shell)

Installation:

```
git clone https://github.com/milkbikis/powerline-shell
./install.py
```